# GetSchema("Databases") on ODBC connection (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I am testing various DB connection methods in C#. In particular, I am testing `SqlConnection` and `OdbcConnection` classes; my DB is SQLServer Express (`.\SQLEXPRESS`). Both are working reasonably well, except in listing available databases on the server.

In my test code I use a `"generic"` `DbConnection` object and a simple factory to create an instance of specific `SqlConnetion` and `OdbcConnetion` subclasses (they both derive from `DbConnection`):

```
DbConnection connection;
switch (connection_type)
{
case DbConnectionType.DBCONN_MSSQL:
   connection = new SqlConnection(...sql connection string...);
   break;
case DbConnectionType.DBCONN_ODBC:
  connection = new OdbcConnection(...odbc connection string...);
  break;
}
```

The trick seems to work well except when I try to get the list of databases on the server:

```
DataTable databases = connection.GetSchema("Databases");
foreach (DataRow database in databases.Rows)
{
   String databaseName = database["database_name"] as String;
   Console.WriteLine(databaseName);
}
```

When `"connection"` is an `OdbcConnection` (and, note, the database is the same), I get an exception saying that `"Databases" key was not found`. I listed all the keys exposed by `GetSchema()`, and the ODBC version returns only a subset of the items exposed by the SQLServer version. I couldn't find any hint about this specific problem. Is it a documented/expected behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

NOTE: here how I build the ODBC connection string:

```
   OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder;

   builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
   builder.Driver = "SQL Server";
   builder.Add("Server", ".\\SQLEXPRESS");
   builder.Add("Uid", "");
   builder.Add("Pwd", ""); // Using current user
   builder.Add("Integrated Security", "SSPI");

   connection = new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a documented/expected behaviour?

Yes.  See [Retrieving Database Schema Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-database-schema-information)

> Am I doing something wrong?

If your goal is to read SQL Server metadata in a provider-agnostic way, then yes.  You should query the SQL Server catalog views directly.  sys.databases, sys.tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "Databases" model has a valid Key. Add the [Key] Data annotation if the key you want to implement for that database doesn't follow the "ClassName"+"ID" entity framework rule.