# Get metadata with ODBC provider

Tags: c#, database, odbc

I am using ODBC driver to connect to SQL Server.

I want to fetch all the databases from the server but I can't get them with `connection.GetSchema()`. And based on [that link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/odbc-schema-collections), there is no **Catalogs** or **Databases** keyword in the schema collection list for ODBC driver.

I'm wondering if there is another way to get all the databases ?

Comment: If the database is SQL Server, you could just query system tables like `sys.databases` and `sys.tables` instead.

Comment: question: why are you using the ODBC driver rather than SqlClient? note: I'm not sure that GetSchema is a great method, but it should at least work...

Comment: @Zer0 let's say that the i'm implementing an ODBC provider and i want to connect to different server, not only SQL.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm using ODBC driver to be able to connect to other servers that support ODBC. I know that for the SqlClient driver it works fine.

Comment: So you're building an alternative to [Microsoft's .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers#net-framework-data-provider-for-odbc) and [my employer's ADO.NET Provider for ODBC Data Sources](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-odbc-st/)? We originally built ours because Microsoft was slow to ship their own, and continued in part because theirs had terrible compatibility with non-Microsoft ODBC drivers ... but both of these factors have eased over time.

Comment: If you're building an ODBC Driver, or building a Bridge to ODBC, you need to use the ODBC API -- and calls like [`SQLTables()`, `SQLColumns()`, `SQLProcedures()`, and `SQLGetTypeInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/catalog-functions-in-odbc?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I don't want to build an ODBC Driver @TallTed . I just want to use an existing driver and fetch all the databases from the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetSchema("Databases") on ODBC connection (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179983/getschemadatabases-on-odbc-connection-c)

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getschema-and-schema-collections) states (emphasis below mine) --

> You can query a .NET Framework managed provider to determine the list of supported schema collections by calling the GetSchema method with no arguments, **or with the schema collection name "MetaDataCollections"**. This will return a DataTable with a list of the supported schema collections, the number of restrictions that they each support, and the number of identifier parts that they use.

In other words, since `connection.GetSchema()` isn't working (though it should); try `connection.GetSchema("MetaDataCollections")`.

Comment: Thx TallTed, but my problem is not to get all the metadata collection. I just want to get the existing databases by using `connection.GetSchema("Databases")` or `connection.GetSchema("Catalogs")` for ODBC provider

Comment: Some discussion about [catalog and other limitations in ADO.NET](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/UdaAdoNet2ProviderMetaDataExtensionsUserDocWP), which remains relevant for the Microsoft Bridge to ODBC, as well as compensating extensions found in [my employer's ADO.NET Provider for ODBC Data Sources](https://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-odbc-st/).